# Twin paradox problem with acceleration, turning issues removed

Tags: special-relativity

Twin Anna leaves Chicago in a supersonic jet, accelerates to Mach 3 then immediately decelerates and lands in New York. Then she climbs into a rowboat and rows slowly to England, landing 3 months later.  Twin Bob waits for 3 months then leaves Chicago in a jet, accelerates to Mach 3 and flies (just above the water) all the way to an aircraft carrier near England, then climbs into a rowboat and rows the last 100 metres.   Which twin is younger?

UPDATE:  I have created the spacetime diagram to show how each moves relative to the other.  The basis of ANY twin paradox question is not how they move relative to other observers (like people in Chicago or New York) but only how they move relative to each other. As you can see in the diagram, from Anna's reference point, Bob moves westward first fast for a few minutes, then slowly for 3 months, then suddenly moves eastward fast for an hour to rejoin her.  From Bob's reference point, Anna moves eastward first fast for a few minutes, then slowly for 3 months, then moves westward fast for an hour to rejoin him.

Twin paradox questions are not concerned with how outside observers see the situation.  The paradox is, when they rejoin Bob would say that Anna is younger while Anna would say that Bob is younger.

We can all agree that Bob is younger because we, as outside observers, can tell that Bob travelled faster than Anna. And this is the problem with interpretations of special relativity that say that "all motion is relative".

[image: Bob and Anna Worldline]

I have read [the Physics Forums Explanation](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/when-discussing-the-twin-paradox-read-this-first/) but it does not seem to cover this situation.

Comment: "They both travel the same distance in spacetime" -- no, they have the same beginning and ending points, just like in the regular twin paradox, but they take different paths through spacetime, just like in the regular twin paradox. To figure out which is younger, you just add up their aging rates along their paths accounting for time dilation.

Comment: The reason the regular twin paradox is a paradox is because somebody could ask "why can't you work in Bob's reference frame and get the opposite answer?" and the answer to that question is that Bob's reference frame is accelerated. In your modified version, _both_ Alice and Bob accelerate so there's no point in working in either's frame. There's no paradox: you just work in the Earth's frame and in that case the answer is straightforward.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148095/discussion-on-question-by-foolishmuse-twin-paradox-problem-with-acceleration-tu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have read the Physics Forums Explanation but it does not seem to cover this situation

The spacetime geometry explanation is completely general. It works for all possible paths through all possible spacetimes. That includes this scenario.

Unfortunately, the Physics Forums link does not show the math. The formula is $$\Delta \tau =\int d\tau = \int \frac{1}{c}\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}$$ In this formula $\tau$ is the proper time measured by one twin, i.e. how much they age. $g$ is the spacetime metric in the frame of interest and $x$ is the coordinates of the twin in the frame of interest. The integral is taken over the worldline of the twin.

Applying this one formula to any situation always gets the correct prediction, including this scenario. You simply calculate the above formula for each twin and compare. The smaller value is the younger twin at the reunion. This formula is manifestly invariant, so all reference frames will agree on the $\tau$ calculated for each twin

Comment: Can you explain how this formula explains the twin paradox issue and relative motion, under which Anna would say motion was relative to her, so Bob should be the younger; while Bob would say motion was relative to him, so Anna should be the younger.  This is the point of the question.

Comment: @foolishmuse I have added some more explanation

Comment: The key point is that the equation is manifestly invariant, meaning that it is written in a form that is explicitly guaranteed to give the same answer in every reference frame

Comment: I am no mathematician, so I'll have to spend the weekend figuring this out.  But what you seem to be saying is that with this formula from Bob's frame of reference, he can say that Anna travelled to him at Mach 3, but he is the younger when they get together.  Have I interpreted this correctly?

Comment: @foolishmuse yes. That is the whole point of writing things in the manifestly invariant form. Bob can use his frame to evaluate this expression for Bob and for Anna. Anna can use her frame to evaluate this expression for Bob and for Anna. They are guaranteed to both agree on the resulting age for Bob. They are guaranteed to both agree on the resulting age for Anna.

Comment: Great. I'm marking your answer as correct because I'm worried the question will be closed again before I get another chance.   It would be helpful if you could point me to an easy reference on how to work out the math of your formula.  I'll spend a lot of time understanding this because it is very important to me and my overall theory.

Comment: @foolishmuse I don’t know about “easy”. These concepts are challenging. But I do like Sean Carroll’s “Lecture Notes on General Relativity”. https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019 Chapter 1 will get you 90% there and Chapters 2 and 3 cover that last bit

Comment: @foolishmuse IMHO: For a piecewise-inertial worldline, the simplified form of the formula is: Given the sequence of vertex-events A1,A2,A3, ... ( $(t,x/c)$ pairs from an underappreciated spacetime diagram), compute $\sqrt{(A2_t-A1_t)^2-(A2_x-A1_x)^2/c^2}+\sqrt{(A3_t-A2_t)^2-(A3_x-A2_x)^2/c^2}+\ldots$ (the analogue of the distance along a path) to determine the proper-time along that piecewise-inertial worldline. I think it's more useful to start with this formula applied to a spacetime diagram with two piecewise-inertial worldlines, and wait until this is clear before moving on to Carroll.

Comment: I've posted a new question and would appreciate your input https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/778273/does-relative-kinetic-time-dilation-work-the-same-as-relative-kinetic-length-con

Answer (score 1):

The point of your question appears to be this- how can one twin age less than the other when time dilation is symmetrical and you have designed your thought experiment to include the same degree of acceleration in the case of each twin?

The answer is that your thought experiment is not symmetrical, and its asymmetry allows one twin to age less than the other.

Time dilation is symmetrical between two inertial frames, so that when the twins are coasting, each is time dilated to the same extent in the frame of the other. However, when the twins switch reference frames by changing speed, you have to take the relativity of simultaneity into account. The key point here is that the effect depends not just on the change of speed but also on how far apart the twins are when one of them accelerates. You can readily see that if you draw a spacetime diagram. When a twin accelerates, their plane of simultaneity tilts, and the effect of the tilt is to advance the time that corresponds to 'now' at the location of the other twin.

The effect of the tilting plane of simultaneity increases with the distance between the twins. When they are close together, the effect is negligible. In your set up, the essential asymmetry arises because Anna undergoes deceleration when she is roughly 700 miles from Bob (ie the distance from Chicago to New York), whereas Bob accelerates when he is about 4,000 miles from Anna (the distance from Chicago to London). The effect of a plane of simultaneity sweeping upwards in the other twin's frame is greatest in Bob's case, and therefore it will be Bob who will age less.

You can get another insight into the nature of the asymmetry if you consider the Doppler effect. Let's suppose the twins are far apart and are sending light pulses to each other at microsecond intervals. If one of the twins accelerates toward the other, they will immediately see an increase in the timing of the pulses from the other twin, whereas there will be a time lag before the other twin sees any effect on the pulses received from the accelerating twin. If you dwell on that point, and perhaps sketch it in a diagram, you will see that it is consistent with the idea that when one twin accelerates toward the other, their tilting plane of simultaneity results in a jump forward in the time that corresponds to their 'now' at the location of the remote twin.

Comment: Sorry but this is a standard twin paradox question, and you've misunderstood my point which is that we have to look at the reference frame of both Anna and Bob.  From Bob's reference, he does not travel to Anna at Mach 3. Rather she travels to him at Mach 3.

Comment: Agreed. But you have missed the point of my answer. I have said that when the twins are coasting, the time dilation effect is reciprocal, but the accelerations are not reciprocal, and the effects of the accelerations depends upon how far apart the twins are at the time. Anna travels toward Bob at Mach 3 only after Bob has changed reference frame by accelerating.

Comment: Surely you are not thinking that acceleration has anything to do with kinetic time dilation, other than that at each instant the inertial velocity has increased? A key point of my original question was to eliminate acceleration from any possible answer.

Comment: Of course it does! You have not eliminated acceleration. Bob and Anna accelerate asymmetrically, and that's what causes the difference in their ageing. If the scenario were truly symmetrical, then Bob and Anna would age by the same amount.

Comment: The effect of acceleration is to bring the relativity of simultaneity into play, which is a factor you are continuing to overlook or misunderstand.

Comment: I will dig into this.

Comment: Sorry but I can't agree with this analysis.  We could easily change the scenario to where Anna does her jet trip to just before arriving in England, 4000 miles from Bob.  Bob would remain younger from all points of reference.

Comment: If Anna's jet trip is changed to be as long as Bob's, then the changed scenario would then be symmetrical and they would both age by equal amounts! If you disagree with my analysis, you are simply misguided. If you are struggling to understand it, fair enough, but it is not wrong.

Comment: These videos seems to remove acceleration from having any impact on the twin paradox as I have described https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGoAZKyI6ZY&list=PL__fY7tXwodlaZp8pCI-Snv6pad5RuSdQ&index=2     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0OI1IFLXGk&list=PL__fY7tXwodlaZp8pCI-Snv6pad5RuSdQ&index=3  Do you have any comments on them?     And for your reference I have added a spacetime diagram to my question.

Comment: Yes, my comments are that they are click-bait nonsense. The say acceleration is relative, which is simply wrong. If you read the final paragraph of my answer, you should be able to see why acceleration at a distance is an import factor which you and the YouTube both fail to recognise. Also, your spacetime diagram is incorrect.

Comment: I've posted a new question and would appreciate your input https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/778273/does-relative-kinetic-time-dilation-work-the-same-as-relative-kinetic-length-con

Answer (score 1):

If Alice travels at speed $v$ for time $t$ (according to those of us who stay home), she ages by $t/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ (again, according to us).   Carefully write down the duration and velocity that you're assuming for each leg of her trip, calculate how much she ages on that leg, and add up over all the legs.  Do the same for Bob.

What is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: Sorry but this is a standard twin paradox question.  We have to look at the reference frame of both Anna and Bob. From Bob's reference, he does not travel to Anna at Mach 3. Rather she travels to him at Mach 3.

Comment: @foolishmuse you are stubbornly missing the point of the answers you are being given. Yes, Anna does move to Bob at Mach 3, but that is irrelevant to the overall outcome. When she is moving relative to Bob at Mach 3, she is time dilated in his frame and he is time dilated in hers to exactly the same degree...

Comment: @foolishmuse the asymmetry that causes them to age by different degrees is associated with their periods of acceleration at a distance. Bob accelerates when he is further away, and that factor causes the discrepancy you have overlooked.

Comment: I will dig into this.

Comment: @foolishmuse:  Yes, you are quite stubbornly missing the point.   You can do all your calculations in whatever frame is most convenient for the problem.   In this case, that is the frame of the people who stayed put in Chicago (or in London).  Once you've got the answer in the most convenient frame, it would be an excellent exercise to repeat the calculation in either the airplane frame or the rowboat frame to make sure you get the same answer.   That recalculation is unnecessary for finding the answer but will go a long way toward clearing up your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with this question is the completely non-relativistic set up. Chicago to London is milliseconds, and speeds are slow. SR is not a factor. The 3 cities aren't collinear, which complicate a quantitative analysis.

There is also the problem that it's on Earth, which will invoke failures to abstract, such as rotating reference frames and gravitation time dilations.

To fix that, imagine 3 collinear deep space stations called CHI, NYC and LON, all with relative velocities zero.

Now pick reasonable velocities, one slow, and one fast:

$$ v_s = \frac{13}{85}$$
$$ v_f = \frac{84}{85}$$

with corresponding Lorentz factors:

$$ \gamma_s = \frac{85}{84}$$
$$ \gamma_f = \frac{85}{13} $$

With CHI defining the origin of the $S$ frame , the world line of CHI is:

$$ W_{CHI}(t) = (t, 0) $$

we'll place the other stations at:

$$ W_{NYC}(t) = (t, 84) $$
$$ W_{LON}(t) = (t, 97) $$

Here $(t, x)$ refers to years and light-years in the $S$ frame.

It's very important to label relevant events when setting up and SR problem. Firing off long sentences describing them is not clear.

So everyone starts at:

$$E_0 = (0,0)$$

At $t=0$, *Alice* (it's always Alice, not Anna) leaves for NYC, traveling in the $S'$ frame at $v_f$, arriving at:

$$E_1 = (\frac{D_{C, N}}{v_f}, D_{C, N})=(85, 84) $$

and immediately slowing to $v_s$, traveling in the $S''$ frame to arrive at LON:

$$E_2 = (170, 97) $$

At that point, Bob leaves for a direct flight to LON at $v_f$:

$$E_3 = (170, 0) $$

traveling in $S'''$, arriving at LON at:

$$ E_4 = \big(85(2+\frac{97}{85}), 97\big) $$

where he slows down to $v_s$ for $\epsilon$, in frame $S''''$, and then stopping, returning to $S$ and reuniting with Alice at:

$$ E_5 \approx E_4 $$

So now we have 6 events and 5 frames to deal with, instead of the standard 3 events and 3 frames in the Twin Paradox.

To figure out the elapsed proper times, we just add the proper time of the straight legs. Nominally, this requires transforming into all the frames, but that is not necessary here.

From $E_0$ to $E_1$, Alice experiences:

$$ \tau^A_{0,1} = \frac{D_{C, N}}{v_f\gamma_f}=13\,{\rm years} $$

From $E_1$ to $E_2$:

$$ \tau^A_{1,2} = 195.15\,{\rm years} $$

Finally, from $E_2$ to $E_5$:

$$ \tau^A_{2,5} = \frac{97\cdot 85}{84}=98.15 \,{\rm years} $$

Her total elapsed time is:

$$ \tau^A_{0, 5} = 307.3\,{\rm years}$$

Meanwhile, Bob is simpler:

$$ \tau_{0,3}^B = 170\,{\rm years} $$
$$ \tau_{3,5}^B = 15.0\,{\rm years} $$

His total elapsed time is:

$$ \tau^A_{0, 5} = 185\,{\rm years}$$

Much less than Alice.

So where's the paradox? A paradox is an apparent contradiction, and there are no contradiction in SR: it is self-consistent. Since I analyzed the whole thing in Minkowski Space, there are no apparent contradiction, thus: no paradox.

I have to breakdown some 3+1 frames to find a possible paradox. That means: how much time did Alice see Bob's clock tick?

From $E_0$ to $E_1$:

$$ t^{A, B}_{(0, 1)} = \frac{D_{C, N} }{ v_f \gamma^2_f} =1.99\,{\rm years} $$

From $E_1$ to $E_2$:

$$ t^{A, B}_{(1, 2)} = 12.7\,{\rm years} $$

Finally $E_2$ to $E_5$:

$$ t^{A, B}_{(2, 5)} = 15.0\,{\rm years} $$

for a total time of:

$$ t^{A, B}_{(0, 5)} = 29.7\,{\rm years} $$

which appears to contradict his proper time of $185\,{\rm years}$.

This is an apparent contradiction, aka: a paradox. The resolution involves the relativity of simultaneity. When Alice changes frames, her definition of "now" back on Earth changes, skipping much of Bob's existence sitting around on Earth aging.

Note that this is not time-dilation, this is the relativity of simultaneity. All observers in SR thought experiments have an infinite lattice of synchronized clocks and rulers, and when Alice goes from $S'$ to $S''$ (and from $S''$ to $S'''$), her lattice of clocks goes out of synch, and she needs to pick new ones.

If you work out the *linear* Lorentz Transformations:

$$ t' = mt + b $$

you will find the missing time. The slope, $m$, is time dilations, while the intercept, $b$, is clock synchronization.

Note that in the problem here, it is *much* more tedious than just doing the standard Twin Paradox, where the time on Earth jumps forward at space twin's turn around. Since I provided labeled events: just do the Lorentz Transformations.

This can be analyzed in general relativity as a gravitational time dilation, as GR contains SR, and GR is self-consistent away from singularities, that is a nice exercise when studying GR. It is not necessary. One problem is that the time on Earth can go forward and backward, depending on the direction of the velocity change. (See: Rietdijk–Putnam argument).

Comment: You added in a lot of complexity that I did not intend.  I just wanted to remove the acceleration and turning around answers that are normally given in twin paradox questions.  But given that, this video, at about 8:40, explains that Lorentz transformations are simply mathematical expressions of spacetime diagrams, and hence to not show any reason why one reference frame is preferred over the other.  Your thoughts?   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGoAZKyI6ZY&list=PL__fY7tXwodlaZp8pCI-Snv6pad5RuSdQ&index=2

Comment: without complexity, aka: numbers, the problem is pointless. I even picked easy numbers (pythagorean triples), that make it simpler.

Comment: Dialect, the youtuber, is just wrong.

Comment: I've posted a new question and would appreciate your input https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/778273/does-relative-kinetic-time-dilation-work-the-same-as-relative-kinetic-length-con